Was Polaris Dawn mission the first time a Starlink laser communication link was made with something besides another Starlink?
Space.com's Sept. 13, 2024 SpaceX's private Polaris Dawn astronauts beam photos to Earth using Starlink satellites includes:

Polaris Dawn next pulled off the first-ever private spacewalk on Thursday (Sept. 12), then followed up that historic achievement with one in the communications sphere— posting on X from orbit for the first time using SpaceX's Starlink broadband satellites.
"Hello Earth — We are so grateful for all the support! Please enjoy two recent photos from our mission and stay tuned for our next message. Sent to you from space over a beam of Starlink laser light — Crew of Polaris Dawn," reads the X post, which was published on Thursday afternoon by the Polaris Program, a three-mission effort organized and funded by billionaire tech entrepreneur Jared Isaacman.

Question: Was Polaris Dawn mission the first time a Starlink laser communication link was made with something besides another Starlink?
I think there are two things to verify here.

Did Crew Dragon use an optical link to communicate to a Starlink satellite?
If so, was this the first time a Starlink optical link was not to another Starlink?

Although the mission's apogee is often (but not always) above most Starlinks, who's radio antennas are downward-looking, the stable perigee of only 190 km means there's plenty of opportunity for the capsule to use radio to link to a Starlink, which could then use its laser to link to another Starlink before the ground link.
Presumably the Starlinks' optical links are primarily sideways-looking so they can talk to each other.

related:

"...extending the Starlink network using longer-range laser comms and relay satellites to reach Mars and Starships in-transit" (Musk & Shotwell)
What technology will SpaceX's StarLink satellites most likely use for sat-to-sat linking? (currently unanswered)
Did the Starlink precursor Tintin satellites ever talk to each other? If so, how? Did they demonstrate an optical communications link? (currently unanswered)


Yes and, as far as I can tell, yes.
If not, that's certainly how it has been reported. Laser-based communications have been tested before but this was a first test of the Starlink laser communications system aboard the Polaris Dawn spacecraft. As far as has been reported by SpaceX (note that they have no reason not to report such a feat), the laser system had never been tested before on a crewed spacecraft, so this was a first. I believe the Starlink laser comms had been tested between satellites in the constellation before but never to another spacecraft; this is certainly how it has been reported in various news articles across the Internet.
By dint of the first crewed spacecraft ever being communicated with via laser being a Dragon capsule, the answer to both your questions is yes. I don't work at SpaceX so obviously I don't know if they've been up to talking to Starship or something through lasers, but as far as has been reported, this was a first test of the laser comms program. According to the Polaris Program website -

The Polaris Dawn crew were the first to test Starlink laser-based communications in space, providing valuable data for future space communications systems necessary for missions to the Moon, Mars and beyond.

- emphasis mine. The Polaris Dawn crew being the first to test the laser-based communications is answer enough. It's entirely possible that they rotated a Starlink sat to be within the correct angle for the comms, or that they just waited to be below them, I'm not sure on the specifics of that but your question has certainly been answered.
Many other news reports cite this as a first for Starlink.
Scientific American:

On Friday—the mission's fourth day in space—the crew plans to test a laser-based communications system for SpaceX's Starlink satellites.

NDTV:

Beyond their spacewalk, the crew will test laser-based satellite communications between the spacecraft and the vast Starlink satellite constellation.

EarthSky:

Also, the mission has used SpaceX's Starlink laser-based communications. This is how we got to see that beautiful violin performance...

ViaSatellite:

The Polaris Dawn civilian astronaut mission will also test out Starlink laser communications aboard the Dragon spacecraft.

PCMag:

Prior to returning to Earth, the Polaris Dawn crew used Starlink's laser network to conduct several live video streams with people on the ground ...


all the secondary sources cited at the end of your answer probably pull from the same primary source, so it isn't notable that many of them cite the same thing.

The point I was making is that it doesn't seem like there are any primary sources saying otherwise. If there were it certainly would've been reported on and the discrepancy would have been highly notable (and probably looked at by bigger news agencies/the FAA/etc).
